# jquery randomly animate div (zoom in and out)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/xwb0d48v/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#zoom-box').animate({
    width:'600px',
    height:'600px',
    top:'0',
    left:'0',
    'font-size':'50px',
    'line-height':'300px'
}, 1000);
});//]]> 
</script>    

</head>

<body>
  <div id="zoom-box">ZOOMING</div>
  <div id="zoom-box2">NO ZOOM YET</div>
  <div id="zoom-box3">NO ZOOM YET</div>
  <div id="zoom-box4">NO ZOOM YET</div>
  <div id="zoom-box5">NO ZOOM YET</div>
  <div id="zoom-box6">NO ZOOM YET</div>
</body>
```

How do I randomly animate (zoom in and zoom out and zoom into another one) all the divs every 5 seconds?

Thanks,

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9uru9bmf/)?

Comment: Forgot to change the `line-height` ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uru9bmf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout for change ever n second the images, you call the timer for example

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

in the event load of you page